# 6502 machine code in apple IIe monitor

Tags: assembly, machine-code, 6502

We have an Apple IIe with no working disk drive. After a bit of searching, I found that the monitor can be used to program machine code, and found an example though with no explanation of how it works.  `300:20 58 FC A9 C8 20 ED FD A9 E9 20 ED FD 20 8E FD 60` What does this mean? Even after finding what all the opcodes are I still can't really figure them out.

Comment: You could have just typed 300L<Return> and it would disassemble this for you. Then you need to look up the addresses accessed or called (as Tommylee2k has done in his answer). For more retro questions I would suggest https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 5):

let's see, google will surely help us

```
20 58 FC A9 C8 20 ED FD A9 E9 20 ED FD 20 8E FD 60
```

http://www.6502.org/tutorials/6502opcodes.html has the opcodes,
http://apple2.org.za/gswv/USA2WUG/FOUNDING.MEMBERS/HOME.PAGES/EDHEL/texts/pokes.html (1) knows some of these addresses, http://apple2.org.za/gswv/a2zine/faqs/csa2pfaq.html (2) knows some more

("300:" is tells us it's going to be stored at $0300)

$20 is JSR, JSR is a 3 byte instruction, so 20 58 FC belong together and is

```
JSR $FC58   ; CLEAR SCREEN (1)
```

A9 is LDA immediately (2 bytes), next 2 bytes A9 C8 is

```
LDA #$C8   ;
```

20 ED FD:

```
JSR $FDED  ; OUTPUT CHARACTER IN ACCUMULATOR. (2)
```

A9 E9

```
LDA #$E9
```

20 ED FD:

```
JSR $FDED ;
```

20 8E FD

```
JSR $FD8E ;  "PRINT CARRIAGE RETURN" (2)
```

60

```
RTS       ;  return
```

the whole thing:

```
org $0300
20 58 FC  JSR $FC58  ; CLEAR SCREEN (1)
A9 C8     LDA #$C8   
20 ED FD  JSR $FDED  ; OUTPUT CHARACTER IN ACCUMULATOR. (2)
A9 E9     LDA #$E9
20 ED FD  JSR $FDED  
20 8E FD  JSR $FD8E  ;  "PRINT CARRIAGE RETURN" (2) 
60        RTS        ;  return
```

so this function will clear the screen, write 2 characters and a CR